Calculating estimated HR and Confidence Interval from coxph object with time-dependent coefficient and splines
How can I calculate hazard ratios (HRs) and confidence intervals at specific time points for a Cox PH model with a time-dependent coefficient and splines?
This is similar to the previous question posed here, except that I would further like to calculate confidence intervals. Furthermore, I am unable to replicate the process in the linked question/answer as my model specification is slightly different. It has also been many years since the linked question, so perhaps there is functionality in existing R packages to do this now available before.
Data
df <- structure(list(time = c(57, 123, 32, 39, 44, 52, 33, 51, 63, 
68, 38, 42, 40, 35, 48, 52, 43, 59, 37, 41, 32, 31, 37, 57, 51, 
31, 35, 41, 43, 51, 32, 43, 61, 37, 38, 33, 35, 35, 40, 57, 42, 
40, 50, 45, 92, 36, 46, 47, 31, 32, 37, 28, 43, 43, 39, 44, 51, 
30, 39, 49, 32, 44, 79, 36, 46, 38, 53, 34, 42, 43, 31, 44, 51, 
36, 98, 89, 32, 40, 38, 37, 40, 35, 47, 44, 26, 38, 40, 27, 53, 
41, 31, 52, 35, 40, 38, 45, 43, 39, 40, 83), status = c(1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), group = c(0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), cat1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), cat2 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Now, I would like to fit the model:
mod <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ group + tt(group) + cat1 + cat2,
             data = df,
             tt = function(x, t, ...) x*pspline(t))

Following the answer in the linked question but changing some values to match my model, I next try:
output <- data.frame(group_time = seq(min(df$time), max(df$time), by = 0.01))
output$HR <- exp(pspline(output$group_time) %*% mod$coefficients[1:13] -
                   sum(mod$means[1:13] * mod$coefficients[1:13]))
Error in pspline(output$group_time) %*% mod$coefficients[1:13] : 
  non-conformable arguments

I believe the non-conformability is due to the fact I have a main effect term for group, which the previous question did not have. And I believe I would need to retain this to correctly calculate HRs. It is not clear to me which component of pspline(output$group_time) is being multiplied by the model coefficients, and what/how to add in to include the main group effect. And, after properly doing that, how to further calculate CIs.
